# Styling on my footer <a> tags only work when I add padding to the form above, why?

Tags: html, css

The problem is that when I style the `<a>` tag for the list in the footer, nothing happens even if it is set up correctly to apply the style. But if I add padding to the form in the main part of the code, suddenly the change shows on the links in the footer.

I have provided a JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/wk47q0en/), just go to line 56 in the css and comment out/delete the random padding that was added to form, and the footer styling disappears. I am wondering why this happens.

And if you wonder, yes I am new to HTML and CSS , it's part of some homework :D  in advance thanks for any advice that help clear this up.

https://jsfiddle.net/wk47q0en/

**HTML**

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Red Pepper Pizza</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="topmenu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Weekly deals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Resturants</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>

  <form action="example.htm" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Order your pizza below</legend>
      <select name="Pizza" id="Pizza">
        <option value="selected" selected>Choose a pizza</option>
        <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="Ham">Ham</option>
        <option value="Vegan">Vegan</option>
        <option value="Margarita">Margarita</option>
      </select>

      <p>Choose your Pizza crust</p>
      <input type="radio" name="Crust" value="Thick"> Thick
      <input type="radio" name="Crust" value="Thin"> Thin

      <p>Extra toppings</p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="Onions"> Onions
      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="Salmon"> Salmon
      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="Garlic"> Garlic
      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="Olives"> Olives
      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="Chilli"> Chilli
      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="Peppers"> Peppers

      <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="62"> Additional specifications...</textarea> <br>

      <input type="submit" name="order" value="order">
      </fieldset>
  </form>

    <footer>
        <div class="footermenu">
           <ul class="footlist">
             <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Job oppertunities</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Allergens</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
    /* body etc */
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    src: url(assets\RobotoFont\Roboto-Regular.ttf);
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0px 10px;
    }

    /* Navigation/topbar/sidebar */

    ul {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    li {
      display: inline;
    }


    .topmenu {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #d12d17;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0px;
      padding-top: 0px;
    }


    .topmenu a {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 40px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 19px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 10px 25px;

    }

    .topmenu a:hover {
      transform: scale(1.3); }
    }


    /*Header and intro*/




    /* Form elements*/

    form {
      padding: 0 50%;
    }



/*footer */

.footlist a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your CSS code at line 48. You have an extra curly bracket. When you style the form element in line 58 the value doesn't actually get applied because of the error but the styling of later elements work properly. When you take out the form element styling the error affects the element that is being styled right after it which is the a element in the footer.